# i want show two div with same id by click button 3 but it show one div only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want show div 3 and last div 3 at same time when i click button 3

button for click to show div element

```html
<button  class="single" target="1">1</button>
<button  class="single" target="2">2</button>
<button  class="single" target="3">3</button>
```

element i want to show

```html
<section>
    <div id="div1" class="target">1</div>
    <div id="div3" class="target">3</div>
    <div id="div2" class="target">2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="target">3</div> 
</section>
```

jquery code

```js
jQuery('.single').click(function(){ 
jQuery('.target').hide();
jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
```

Comment: IDs in HTML are unique, meaning two elements can never have the same ID. That is why your code only shows the first element with the matching ID. Maybe rethink your html to use classes or data attributes instead.

Comment: Try using class instead of id.